# Debugging: How to show a seq of nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm missing the ability to print

```
    "The median cannot be found"
```

based on there being nothing in the sequence. This is my current code using None, which doesn't work.

```
def print_median(seq):
   if print_median(sep) = None:
      print("The median cannot be found.")
   else:
      median = (seq[len(seq) // 2 - 1] + seq[len(seq) // 2]) / 2
      print("The median of " + str(seq) + " is " + str(median) + ".")
```

Also tried using ((),) and a few random attempts that didn't work either. 
The expected outcome is

```
    >>> print_median(())
    The median cannot be found.
```

as well as producing

```
    >>> print_median((-12, 0, 3, 9))
    The median of (-12, 0, 3, 9) is 1.5.
```

for when there are numbers inputed to the seq.

Comment: Do you mean if nothing is passed to the function or what is passed is an empty sequence?

Comment: Just do `if not seq: print("The median cannot be found.")`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Your line `if print_median(sep) = None` seems to have two problems: `sep` isn't defined, but even if it is, you can't use variable assignment in an `if` statement. Instead, use `==` for equality, or `is None` if you want to be fancy.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, Python sequences are falsy if and only if they are empty.

```
if seq:
  ...
else:
  print("The median cannot be found.")
```

Comment: The issue is that a generator will always be `True` yet may be empty...

Comment: The OP won't be passing a generator, given that he uses `[]` access and `len()` in the nonempty case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are limiting your function to a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), you can just test the sequence for False since empty containers are `False` in Python:

```
def print_median(seq):
   if not seq:
      print("The median cannot be found.")
   else:
      median = (seq[len(seq) // 2 - 1] + seq[len(seq) // 2]) / 2
      print("The median of " + str(seq) + " is " + str(median) + ".")
```

The will only deal with sequences and will fail on something like `print_median(range(10))` in Python 3.

Given you are writing for Python 3 where many items are [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), I would rewrite your function to use `try` and `except` and to handle generators by calling `list` on the sequence passed:

```
def print_median(seq):
    items=list(seq)
    try:
        median = (items[len(items) // 2 - 1] + items[len(items) // 2]) / 2
        print("The median of {} is {}.".format(items, median))
    except IndexError:
        print("The median cannot be found.")
```

That will now handle generators and lists and empty sequences as you expect:

```
>>> print_median([1,2,3])
The median of [1, 2, 3] is 1.5.
>>> print_median(e for e in [1,2,3])
The median of [1, 2, 3] is 1.5.
>>> print_median(range(10))
The median of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] is 4.5.
>>> print_median([])
The median cannot be found.
```